# How to mix beers?

Tags: beer, beer-styles, experiments

I know this question doesn't really comply to standards but, I wanted to know if we can mix beers after, say cold crash. I want to create different beers using the ones I already brewed.

Can I mix ales with lagers for example?

I know big breweries mix different batches to keep the profile stable. But, I want to do this to create new and more complex beers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. In fact I did it a few times myself, blending too dark beers for my taste with some lighter beers to create the perfect depth.

But, if the mixed beers use different yeast strains, it is possible they both have different attenuation levels. The yeast from one beer can continue to ferment the sugars of the other beer. Fermentation starts again and this can be a problem when you bottle the mixed beer again. If you mix in the glass, go crazy and try different combinations and ratio's.